# How to solve the "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error

Tags: sql-server

Hi is it possible to make something like that?

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN STH1 IN (SELECT STH1 FROM DATABASE1) 
    THEN (SELECT STH1 FROM DATABASE1) 
    ELSE (SELECT STH1 FROM DATABASE2) END
FROM [test].[CDN].[TwrKarty]
```

Or maybe there is other way to solve my problem. I want to show everything(from first database) when it's IN second database when ?Option =1 else everything what isn't in second database.

When im trying to do the first way i get this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. –

Example: When my option =1(eg. 1=1) then i'd like to get

```
 SELECT number FROM shipment WHERE (number IN (SELECT number FROM shipment_desc))
```

When my option =2 then i'd like to get

```
SELECT number FROM shipment WHERE (number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM shipment_desc))
```

It's SQL Server.

Comment: When im trying to do the first way i get this error
 `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: are you talking about databases or tables? the error is pretty straightforward to understand. If you explain what you want to achieve, give us some sample data and expected results maybe we can assist you. this way your question is not clear

Comment: Are you trying to query across multiple databases? Or are those really the table names?

Comment: If those are actual table names, that's weird, but you can look into using `JOIN`s to get what you are looking for.

Comment: Tag properly!!  You tag `MySQL`, but your code looks like `SQL Server`.  Which one is right??

Comment: Also, you can't select from database.  You select from table.

Comment: Sorry.
Example:
When my option =1(eg. 1=1) then i'd like to get `SELECT number
  FROM shipment
WHERE (number IN (SELECT number
  FROM shipment_desc))`
When my option =2 then i'd like to get `SELECT number
  FROM shipment
WHERE (number NOT IN (SELECT number
  FROM shipment_desc))`
It's SQL Server. Sorry again :)

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.  Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask